# Is there any open source solver for MILP that can output the top N best results instead of the global best?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, open-source, callback

I am working on an MILP problem, and the project needs to output the top N best results rather than the global best. I am looking for an open source solver which has a callback function. Can anyone provide help on this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but you can do it yourself with any solver by adding a set of [no good cuts](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/no-good-cuts-for-general-integer-variables) to sequentially exclude previous optimal solutions.

Comment: Great! This works for my case. But found another problem, the model does not report infeasible during the loop, instead, it always output the same solution as the previous one.

Comment: There is certainly a bug in your code. Feel free to open a new question, with your code, and we will be glad to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3):

No, i am not aware of such a solver. However sequentially excluding previously optimal results comes with an additional pitfall: If the solver discovered symmetries and did cut them away you also exclude symmetric solutions although they would rank before the next best objective.